# cancelling current task and reuse the same thread while creating another task in java

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, threadpoolexecutor, java-threads

**Please take time to read below. Your help will be highly appreciated**

I have a scenario where I need to monitor some realtime activity. Say for example a method is getting called in realtime within milli seconds. I have to monitor as if when the method was first called and when the method was called last.

So, after that method is hit last I need to wait for sometime say 10 seconds and see if it doesn't called again within that time. If its not called then I need to run some code.

I want to use **ExecuterService** and use **newCachedThreadPool()**. But I am confused on how to implement this.

If you are not sure what I am talking about, take some example of say when there is some network breakdown and u where receiving heartbeats and suddenly u stopped receiving it then you show some error message on screen for e.g. Connection not available. In my case its some third party application which is sending some message and its just one way communication. Like, my application sent some request and other application keep on sending responses. So, I need to monitor that response and somehow need to know when I received the last response.

**My approach** - I thought of executing a task each time that method is called which will wait for 10 seconds and within 10 seconds, if that method got called again, it will somehow cancel the current task and will create another task (or reuse if possible) which will again run for 10 seconds. This will keep on happening until the last message received (when the method got called last) and after that once 10 sec delay is over, the task will be executed and some code will run to show error message on the UI.

I have used Timer earlier, which solved this problem but created a performance issue as new Timer which a new TimerTask is instantiated every time a new message is received hence creating a hell lot of objects which garbage collector could not reclaim that fast, thus resulting in outOfMemorry Error and making Server non responsive. Obviously it was a bad code that's why I am here for help.

Please help me in giving some approach to solve this problem.

Comment: I always thought that ThreadPools provide ease of use over control. If I were doing this I would not use them but this is my personal taste

Comment: Do you want to raise an alarm if some application code is not executed in t seconds? Is that the problem statement? If yes, please rephrase your question to clearly state that. If not, still rephrase your question to state the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy if you approach it with the most basic of tools--sometimes with simple problems the enhanced tools like thread pools just distract from a trivial solution.

Let's say you have a simple thread (Runnable).  That thread checks a time stamp to see if that time stamp is 10 seconds old.  If it is you notify your listener, if not you delay a few millis and check again.

Now all your method has to do is update the (volatile) time stamp to "now" every time it runs.  There may be some other business rules to implement here but it should be a good foundation.

The only issue now is how you notify your listeners.  If this happens rarely you can probably call them on the same thread you are checking the time with--but I think you ruled that out.  If it happens more often but you don't want/need it to "nest" your notifications, you can have a second thread hanging around with no purpose except to notify the client when triggered by your watcher thread.

If you need to "nest" notifications (notify the listener before the original notification has returned) then you need a thread pool for your notifications to go out on.

Finally I suppose if you want to catch EVERY time your timer isn't called for 10 seconds but you don't want to nest,  your timing thread could push "events" onto a threadsafe queue and your "Notification" thread could pull them off and send the events one at a time.

That should cover all the possibilities.

Comment: That was exactly what I was thinking, too. But as I only have my mobile phone and got my 300 rep today anyway I am glad you decided to write down this answer. One hint: volatile would not be required if the threads reading /writing the time stamp synchronize on the same monitor. But I am not sure which option gives better "real time performance".

Comment: @GhostCat true, thank you.  You could probably also use an AtomicLong--I'm guessing that would actually be the best for both performance and ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

You may use ScheduledExecutorService.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Answer (score -1):

`java.util.concurrent.Executors.newCachedThreadPool` :

> Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will
>   reuse previously constructed threads when they are available. These
>   pools will typically improve the performance of programs that execute
>   many short-lived asynchronous tasks. Calls to execute will reuse
>   previously constructed threads if available. If no existing thread is
>   available, a new thread will be created and added to the pool. Threads
>   that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed
>   from the cache. Thus, a pool that remains idle for long enough will
>   not consume any resources. Note that pools with similar properties but
>   different details (for example, timeout parameters) may be created
>   using ThreadPoolExecutor constructors

As you have many short-lived tasks, cached thread pool is best option.

Short example:

```
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    private String command;

    public WorkerThread(String s){
        this.command=s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Start. Command = "+command);
        processCommand();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" End.");
    }

    private void processCommand() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.command;
    }
}
```

To run `WorkerThread` use :

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("threadName");
            executor.execute(worker);
```

To stop `WorkerThread` use:

```
executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: This is not even remotely helpful to the OP. What he wants is some sort of signalling between his app code and monitoring code, not how to implement a `Runnable`, for which, Google already has a few million examples.

Comment: He said : `I want to use ExecuterService and use newCachedThreadPool(). But I am confused on how to implement this.`

Comment: He thinks he needs `ExecuterService` but if you read the rest of his rather long and somewhat confusing question, you'll see what I said above.

Comment: BTW, I didn't downvote you, but I see someone else did.

Comment: How can we monitor method calls in java?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+can+we+monitor+method+calls+in+java&oq=How+can+we+monitor+method+calls+in+java&aqs=chrome..69i57.224j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

There are many ways, and it's not a specific question. I'm gonna recommend that the OP's question is too broad, and he needs to narrow it down.

Comment: I didn't down vote you either but reading carefully the problem(s) a pool is not the best option